# Getting started with e4 OSGI application with e(fx)clipse

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, efxclipse

I'm very new to the all of OSGI development and JavaFX. I was trying to get started on developing an sample application using the Eclipse 4 platform and the e(fx)clipse runtimes, etoolings, etc.

I downloaded the pre-bundled version of the eclipse available at http://efxclipse.bestsolution.at/install.html#all-in-one

- I Started a new project using New > JavaFX > OSGI > e4 Application projects.
- I edited the `Application.e4xmi` file to add a trimmed window, perspective stack, a perspective, with a part sash container containing two parts.

Ran the application, and it showed up fine with a main window and two parts separated by the horizontal part separated.

I then edited the model to change the part sash container to horizontal, added a third part and tried to re-run the application. It showed no change to the window.

I tried adding a menu and adding trims with a few sample elements, but nothing I tried seemed to change the UI. I've tried to clean the project, restart the IDE. None of this has helped. I get no errors, just a couple of log messages.

I'm have the latest JDK 8 installed and edited my `eclipse.ini` file to ensure that I was running the eclipse instance with that JDK (I have multiple JDK's on my machine and in a few other projects, I need JDK 7)

Can anyone help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. This problem seems to have appeared in much older versions as well, and the solution is documented here: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1074739/

Answer (score 0):

In debug configuration select your project and then, in tab main chack clean